# How to get rid of StringTemplate warning "\n in string"

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I'm using StringTemplate 4 to generate some Java source files.

The templates are really simple, e.g.:

```
QueryHandler(method) ::="
public class Obtenir<method.name>Handler extends QueryHandler\<List\<<method.name>Db>> implements IQueryHandler\<List\<<method.name>>>{
    private IQuery\<List\<<method.name>Db>> query;
    private <method.name>Converter converter;

    @Inject
    public Obtenir<method.name>Handler(IQuery\<List\<<method.name>Db>> query, <method.name>Converter converter, IStatisticsCollecter theStatsCollecter){
        super(theStatsCollecter);
        if(query == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(\"The query argument cannot be null\");
        }
        if(converter == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(\"Illegal argument for converter(null)\");
        }
        this.query = query;
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public List\<<method.name>> handle(Object... params) throws JdbcException {
        final String method = \"obtenir<method.name>\";
        DaoQueryStatusCallable status = new DaoQueryStatusCallable();
        List\<<method.name>Db> result = invoke(query, status, method);
        return converter.convert(result);
    }

 }
"
```

The code is even simpler:

```
STGroup group = new STGroupFile("src/main/resources/QueryHandler.stg");
ST wsTemplate = group.getInstanceOf("QueryHandler");
wsTemplate.add("method", m);
System.out.println(wsTemplate.render());
```

The template lines are separated by Unix EOLs (\n). 
When I execute the code, StringTemplate is emitting a warning "QueryHandler.stg 1:25: \n in string".

The result is correct, but I'd still like to get rid of this message.

Anybody ever had this problem and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

t() ::= "..." is meant only for single lines. Please use

```
t() ::= <<
...
>>
```

to get multi-line templates.
Ter